# Drag and drop text in Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

How can I enable the ability to drag-and-drop text in Adobe Brackets?

For example, when I select text and drag it in Sublime Text, it moves. How can I do the same in Bracket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `dragDropText` setting.

To enable it, insert this line into your [preferences file](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences):

```
"dragDropText": true
```

(Note: You may need to reload Brackets for the changes to take effect)

Voilà! Drag-and-drop that text! :)

Happy coding!

Comment: @Anton, if this answer has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Happy Coding!

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work on my machine Ubuntu :(

Comment: I swear I'd like to understand why hell Adobe does not enable that so basic coding requirement by default. We have to take json classes in order to use Brackets haha

Answer (score 4):

**1**- go to menu-->Debug
**2**- go to "open Preferences File"
**3**- go to the file : "brackets.json"
**4**- copy and pase these codes on last line and dont forget separate last code with this by ",":

```
    "dragDropText": true
```

*HOPE TO HELP :))